# URL not redirecting in SWITCH PHP

Tags: php, url

why is it that the URL is not redirecting when I use `header("location".base_url()."dashboard");` in the case `delete` but it is working fine on the default.

```
switch ($action) {
    case 'edit':
        echo "edit";
        break;
    case 'delete':
        $this->Project->delete($id);
        header("location" . base_url() . "dashboard");
        break;
    case 'view':
        echo "view";
        break;
    case 'status':
        echo "status";
        break;
    default:
        header("location:" . base_url() . "dashboard/project/add?error=2");
        break;
}
```

Is there something wrong here?

Comment: you have to double check the $action variable, it seems that "delete" is not the value and that's why it won't match the case condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the colon `:` to separate the header name (`Location`) from its value:

```
case 'delete':
    $this->Project->delete($id);
    header("location: ".base_url()."dashboard");
    break;
```

Comment: Oh my God. That piece of colon. Thanks BTW.